# Selenium webdriver and Linux

Tags: selenium, testng

This is more of a question for information than for help because i really don't know if it works like this or not .
So i created a `.bat` file that works fine in windows and i want to execute it in a **linux** environment but I don't know if i will need pre-requisite so that my `.bat` file runs in linux environement too.

my bat file :

```
set projectLocation=../Demo_Automatisation
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
pause
```

FYI : the plan is to put it in git and run it from jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create sh file.

```
export projectLocation=../Demo_Automatisation
cd $projectLocation
export classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
```

Comment: is it needed specialy in linux ?

Comment: yes. bat files can be executed only on windows

Comment: so do i need to create a duplicate of my .bat add to it what you wrote and give it .sh ?

Comment: yes. if you want to run it in different environment

Comment: ok i will try it ty